# Why is the letter "w" the only letter in (basic) English alphabet that is not read as one syllable?

Tags: alphabet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a w a “Double u”, but an m is not a “Double n”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50117/why-is-a-w-a-double-u-but-an-m-is-not-a-double-n)

Is there any reason/history as to why "w" is the only letter in English alphabet that is not pronounced as one syllable?

Comment: @MattЭллен Not really. That question implies more on the visual representation of the alphabet rather than it's pronunciation.

Comment: Except that the answer is the same.

Comment: I've always wanted to go on Wheel of Fortune, just so I could say, "I'll have a *D*, as in *double-u*."

Answer (score 6):

*W* was originally written as *uu*, or *double u*, as this extract from the OED’s etymological note on *w* explains:

> The ordinary sign for /w/ was at first *uu* , but in the 8th c. this
>   began to be superseded by ƿ, a character borrowed from the Runic
>   alphabet, in which its name was *wyn* (Kentish *wen* ). Eventually the
>   use of ƿ became almost universal, but in the mean time the *uu* was
>   carried from England to the continent, being used for the sound /w/ in
>   the German dialects, and in French proper names and other words of
>   Germanic and Celtic origin. In the 11th c. the ligatured form was
>   introduced into England by Norman scribes, and gradually took the
>   place of ƿ, which finally went out of use about a.d. 1300. The
>   character *W* was probably very early regarded as a single letter,
>   although it has never lost its original name of ‘double U’.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is. I'm sorry, but that is the only real answer to the question. In French "w" has a polysyllabic name, but so does "y"; in German "y" has a polysyllabic name.

It's historical accident.

By the way an "alphabet" means a complete set of letters a-z (or whatever the list is in another language). The individual items are called "letters".